# SQL syntax at joining 2 tables via aliases for resulting tables?

Tags: sql, join, syntax, inner-join

I'm trying to get sense into SQL. Am I correct following the logic below ? Can I use brackets as much as here ?

```
-- 1
(table1) inner join (table2) on ( ??? )

-- 2
(table1 as a) inner join (table2 as b) on (a.col1 = b.col1)

-- 3
((select ... from ... where ...) as a)
    inner join
((select ... from ... where ...) as b)
    on (a.col1 = b.col1)
```

This doesn't work for me.

---

My failing query:

```
((select CREATEDATE, BELEGNRRECH, MNR, UTNR, KTXT
from INFOR.RELFBR
where (SAINT = '90') and (CREATEDATE >= '01.01.14 00:00:00')) as a)
    inner join
((select ANR, MNR from INFOR.RELXDB where (SAINT = '10')) as b)
    on (a.MNR = b.MNR)

-- error message: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I'm using C# to send SQL queries:

```
string q1 = "select CREATEDATE, BELEGNRRECH, MNR, UTNR, KTXT from INFOR.RELFBR " +
    "where (SAINT = '90') and (CREATEDATE >= '" + date.ToString("dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss") + "')";
string q2 = "select ANR, MNR from INFOR.RELXDB where (SAINT = '10')";
string query = "(" + q1 + ") as a inner join (" + q2 + ") as b on (a.MNR = b.MNR)";

// q1 and q2 work, not query
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inner join
((select ANR, MNR from INFOR.RELXDB where (SAINT = '10')) as b)
    on (a.MNR = b.MNR)
```

Should be

```
inner join
(select ANR, MNR from INFOR.RELXDB where (SAINT = '10')) as b
    on (a.MNR = b.MNR)
```

Select in brackets should have alias outside to be used in `ON`

Comment: Didn't work for me either. error: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
SELECT RE.CREATEDATE, RE.BELEGNRRECH, RE.MNR,RE.UTNR, RE.KTXT,REL.ANR, REL.MNR FROM 
INFOR.RELFBR RE INNER JOIN INFOR.RELXDB REL  ON RE.MNR = REL.MNR 
WHERE RE.SAINT = '90' AND RE.CREATEDATE >= '01.01.14 00:00:00' AND  REL.SAINT = '10'
```

Comment: error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: Well, as I read it, it makes sense to me. But I still get errors. This time: `ORA_00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: Does it indicates where is the problem is?

Comment: No, I'm using C# to send queries. And it tells me no lines of error.

Comment: what is the oracle client you are using?

Comment: Dunno. Dunno how to check. I think I'll just select the tables and compare values in C#. SQL fails its whole purpose. It's a big mess.

Comment: Try to run this query in DBMS,then you would be able to find out where is the error.